# Why is my output different when the code is same?

Tags: python, audio-processing, bytesio

I am currently putting together a band-pass filter using the following code: https://ipython-books.github.io/116-applying-digital-filters-to-speech-sounds/

I made few edits to the above code, namely the file is no longer pulled from an url but instead from a local WAV file. Here are the associated edits

```
def speak(voice):
    audio = pydub.AudioSegment.from_wav(BytesIO(voice))    

    with tempfile.temporaryfile() as fn:
        wavef = audio.export(fn, format='wav')
        wavef.seek(0)                            
        wave = wavef.read()
...

voice = open("C:\\Users\\tkim1\\Documents\\librosa\\NEUT 41s 
shaking_gold.wav", "rb").read
```

Currently the "audio = pydub.AudioSegment.from_wav" line of the code outputs the following error:  a bytes-like object is required, not 'builtin_function_or_method." I have gone over the two scripts line by line and cannot determine why this error is surfacing. Thank you so much for reading everyone. Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you "made a few edits", then the code isn't "the same" as your title suggests.

Comment: mr lurker with the logic over here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't call `read`, which is a method.

```
voice = open("...", "rb").read()
#                             ^
```

Comment: thank you for the help Daniel. I am still new to coding and am making elementary mistakes.